# Handling exception when the data(json) is not in required format in dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I had written a script in which a dataframe has a column with in the format of nested json. If any entry in the column is in required format it gives the result but there are many entries where the same required entries are not there and gives KeyError and TypeError. I am trying to do exception handling where the required entry is not there it returns none.

```
Working on individual cells of the columns it gives the correct result like this:

out = json.loads(json.loads(df['RES'][1]).get('output')).get('title')

O/p

'ABC'
```

and if in json 'title' or 'output' is missing it returns none(eg: in df['RES'][0] it was not there)

```
out = json.loads(json.loads(df['RES'][0]).get('output')).get('title')

O/p

None
```

But when I run the same for the entire column entries using 'for' loop and including the exception as well if is not working:

```
for i in df['RES']:
    try:
        out = json.loads(json.loads(df['RES'][i]).get('output')).get('title')
        print(out)
    except (KeyError,TypeError):
        print('None')

o/p:

None 
None
.
.
(None)for the entire rows of that column

wheareas expected o/p has to be:

None
ABC
.
.
and so on
```

Please let me know where I am doing the mistake as for single rows it is working but in loop returning all None.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, here `i` is not the index, it is the entry in the column `RES`

Try `for i in range(len(df['RES'])):` instead